# 64bit version of DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv"

Tags: vba, 64-bit

Is there a 64bit version of the Function `DeviceCapabilities` in the winspool.drv library? What I'm looking for is a conversion of:

```vb
Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
    Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" (ByVal lpDeviceName As String, _
    ByVal lpPort As String, ByVal iIndex As Long, lpOutput As Any, _
    ByVal dev As Long) As Long
```

Clearly I change `Declare Function` to `Declare PtrSafe Function` but which of the `Long` variable change and do they change to `LongLong` or `LongPtr`? Strange that a trawl of the internet over the last hour hasn't turned up any reference to this?

Comment: The last argument changes, it is a pointer.  You can't use it, always pass 0.

Comment: So ByVal dev As LongPtr and always pass 0

Comment: `ByVal iIndex As Integer`, `ByVal dev As LongPtr`.

Answer (score 1):

[Programmatically retrieve printer capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/printing/programmatically-retrieve-printer-capabilities)

I modified this linked code in Microsoft Access to work with 64-bit.
And, by executing Reference Setting "Microsoft ACCESS XX.0 Object Library", I modified the following code to work in Microsoft Excel.
However, the following code is one different: That is the original code

`For lngCounter = 1 To lngPaperCount`

However, this code will cause an error.
The occurrence of this error is avoided by performing minus one.

`For lngCounter = 1 To lngPaperCount -1`

You may think such a following code, but code will cause an error, too.

`For lngCounter = 0 To lngPaperCount`

I don't know if my printer is causing the error or my 64bit Microsoft Office is causing the error.

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" (ByVal lpsDeviceName As String, _
ByVal lpPort As String, ByVal iIndex As Long, lpOutput As Any, _
ByVal lpDevMode As Long) As Long
#Else
' Declaration for the DeviceCapabilities function API call.
Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" (ByVal lpsDeviceName As String, _
ByVal lpPort As String, ByVal iIndex As Long, lpOutput As Any, _
ByVal lpDevMode As Long) As Long
#End If
' DeviceCapabilities function constants.
Private Const DC_PAPERNAMES = 16
Private Const DC_PAPERS = 2
Private Const DC_BINNAMES = 12
Private Const DC_BINS = 6
Private Const DEFAULT_VALUES = 0

Sub GetPaperList()
Dim lngPaperCount As Long
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim hPrinter As Long
Dim strDeviceName As String
Dim strDevicePort As String
Dim strPaperNamesList As String
Dim strPaperName As String
Dim intLength As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim aintNumPaper() As Integer

On Error GoTo GetPaperList_Err

' Get the name and port of the default printer.
strDeviceName = Access.Application.Printer.DeviceName
strDevicePort = Access.Application.Printer.Port

' Get the count of paper names supported by the printer.
lngPaperCount = DeviceCapabilities(lpsDeviceName:=strDeviceName, _
    lpPort:=strDevicePort, _
    iIndex:=DC_PAPERNAMES, _
    lpOutput:=ByVal vbNullString, _
    lpDevMode:=DEFAULT_VALUES)

' Re-dimension the array to the count of paper names.
ReDim aintNumPaper(1 To lngPaperCount)

' Pad the variable to accept 64 bytes for each paper name.
strPaperNamesList = String(64 * lngPaperCount, 0)

' Get the string buffer of all paper names supported by the printer.
lngPaperCount = DeviceCapabilities(lpsDeviceName:=strDeviceName, _
    lpPort:=strDevicePort, _
    iIndex:=DC_PAPERNAMES, _
    lpOutput:=ByVal strPaperNamesList, _
    lpDevMode:=DEFAULT_VALUES)

' Get the array of all paper numbers supported by the printer.
lngPaperCount = DeviceCapabilities(lpsDeviceName:=strDeviceName, _
    lpPort:=strDevicePort, _
    iIndex:=DC_PAPERS, _
    lpOutput:=aintNumPaper(1), _
    lpDevMode:=DEFAULT_VALUES)

' List the available paper names.
strMsg = "Papers available for " & strDeviceName & vbCrLf
For lngCounter = 1 To lngPaperCount

    ' Parse a paper name from the string buffer.
    strPaperName = VBA.Mid(String:=strPaperNamesList, _
        Start:=64 * (lngCounter - 1) + 1, Length:=64)
    intLength = VBA.InStr(Start:=1, String1:=strPaperName, String2:=Chr(0)) - 1
    strPaperName = VBA.Left(String:=strPaperName, Length:=intLength)

    ' Add a paper number and name to text string for the message box.
    strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & aintNumPaper(lngCounter) _
        & vbTab & strPaperName

Next lngCounter

' Show the paper names in a message box.
MsgBox Prompt:=strMsg

GetPaperList_End:
Exit Sub

GetPaperList_Err:
MsgBox Prompt:=Err.Description, Buttons:=vbCritical & vbOKOnly, _
    Title:="Error Number " & Err.Number & " Occurred"
Resume GetPaperList_End

End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice to find this. In Excel VBA I use these: `strDeviceName = Trim$(Left$(ActivePrinter, InStr(ActivePrinter, " on ")))` and `strDevicePort = Trim$(Mid$(ActivePrinter, InStrRev(ActivePrinter, " ") + 1))` and `For lngCounter = 1 To lngPaperCount` works fine.

Answer (score -3):

I have now used the above function by declaring as follows:

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
        Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" (ByVal lpDeviceName As String, _
        ByVal lpPort As String, ByVal iIndex As Long, lpOutput As Any, _
        ByVal dev As Long) As Long
```

For the function to work the API code line

```vb
sCurrentPrinter = Trim$(Left$(ActivePrinter,  InStr(ActivePrinter, " on ")))
```

needs to be changed to

```vb
sCurrentPrinter = ActivePrinter
```